# Stop iTunes from attempting to update carrier settings every time I connect my iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes

I'm irritated by the iTunes prompt to check for update to the carrier settings every time I connect the iPhone (or when the lightning cable moves, which happens a lot of times).

Even after allowing it to check, nothing happens and the dialogue pops up next time.

[image]

I have enabled settings to prevent iPods, iPhones, etc. from syncing automatically:

[image]

iOS: 12.1.1
macOS: 10.14.2 (Mojave)

Please help me with stopping the appearance of this dialogue box.

Comment: Is your iPhone able to make cellular phone calls normally and access the Internet using mobile data? Are you using a beta version of iOS and/or macOS?

Comment: the cell is working perfectly fine on network. and yes both ios and macos are beta

Comment: I'm not sure if this is happening because of beta version of iOS. After the initial setup, an iPhone typically automatically fetches and updates the carrier settings (on its own or via iTunes on macOS/Windows). Once updated, the prompt never reappears. You may wish to have a look through this Apple Support document, [Update your carrier settings on your iPhone or iPad](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201270).